# VPN compatible with iPhone/iPad WITHOUT GRE protocol

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

Is there any VPN which is compatible with iPhone/iPad and works WITHOUT GRE protocol (my router not support GRE)

Comment: You willing to jailbreak?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Apple KB article HT1288](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1288). Cisco IPSec, Juniper Junos Pulse, Cisco AnyConnect and L2TP/IPSec VPNs are supported either within the iOS or via third party apps in the app store. See if you can set up an IPSec/L2TP VPN behind your router. [This excellent and detailed thread at LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ipsec-l2tp-vpn-server-on-ubuntu-for-iphone-718264/) shows how a fellow created an L2TP IPSec VPN on an Ubuntu box for his iPhone to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I found, that L2TP works very nice and require only few UDP ports.